# How do I use React Navigation to navigate to a new screen outside of the render function, and not using JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, react-navigation

I'm fairly new at React, React Native, and React Navigation. Making some progress, but running into this issue.

Normally I'd navigate to a new page by doing something like this:

```
<Button
  text='View Details' onPress={() => 
  this.props.navigation.navigate('AccountScreen')} />
```

However, I'm currently trying to navigate to a new screen in a `.fetch()`, and wondering what I need to do differently.

See code below:

```
// AppNavigation.js:
...
const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  AccountScreen: { screen: AccountScreen }
});



// HomeScreen.js
...
handlePress = (navigator) => {

  fetch('https://example.com/this/url/works' + this.state.accountName, lookUpObject ).then( function(response) {
    if(response.ok) {

      // this does not work. 
      // returns this error:
      // "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.navigate')"
      navigator.navigate( 'AccountScreen', { "accountName": this.state.accountName } );
    }
  })

}

render () {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

  reutrn (
    <ButtonCTA onPress={this.handlePress}>Go to account page</ButtonCTA>
  )
}
```

Right now I get the following error:
`"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.navigate')"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to pass navigator into `handlePress`
Your button code should look like this:

```
<ButtonCTA onPress={ ()=>this.handlePress(this.props.navigation) }>Go to account page</ButtonCTA>
```

Comment: Hrm ... good catch, but I'm still getting the same error:
`E ReactNativeJS: { [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.navigate')]`. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You should also change the `function` in

      `fetch('https://example.com/this/url/works' + this.state.accountName, lookUpObject ).then( function(response) {`


to use the arrow syntax.

Comment: Okay I actually had a few things I needed to change, but I'm going to mark this as the answer, as it basically got me there. I had a typo in my StackNavigator (ugh) and I passed in `navigation` instead of `navigator. Hope this helps someone!